# Export html into pdf landscape mode

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, export

Here is my javascript code for export to pdf.How can i make it in landscape mode.How to change the paper format into A3

```
function Export() {
            html2canvas(document.getElementById('order-listing'), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                    var docDefinition = {
                        content: [{
                            image: data,
                            width: 1000
                        }]
                    };
                    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("detailedattendance.pdf");
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add pageOrientation to the docDefinition array.  Found in documentation [here](https://packagist.org/packages/bpampuch/pdfmake).

```
function Export() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('order-listing'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    width: 1000
                }],
                pageSize: 'A3',
                pageOrientation: 'landscape'
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("detailedattendance.pdf");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How to change it to A3 paper mode @Kenneth

Comment: I've added that option to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try the same using dompdf.